# Crawl a webpage where the input come from a textbox

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, urllib2

I want to crawl this site: https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do

My aim is to write a python script that will alert me as soon as the status on this webpage changes, after entering the receipt number.

I have never done this before but did some reading on here: some have recommended `urllib2` and others `scrapy`. I have a very very basic understanding of how this works.

But here is my problem:

When I enter a receipt number, the url of the webpage does not change after submission. Looking at the source page, I see where you need to enter the receipt number:

```
<input id="receipt_number" name="appReceiptNum" class="form-control textbox  initial-focus" maxlength="13" type="text">`
```

How do I pass this receipt number info into either `urllib2` or `scrapy` or any other method. An example of a receipt number is `EAC1590674053`.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website makes use of a `Form`. So you need to make scrapy to fill out the fields and submit the form. I've compiled some code to show how that can be done with `scrapy`:

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'casestatus'
    start_urls = ['https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do']

    def parse(self, response):

        request = scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formname='caseStatusForm',
            formdata={'appReceiptNum': 'EAC1590674053'},
            callback=self.parse_caseStatus
        )
        print request.body
        yield request

    def parse_caseStatus(self,response):
        sel_current_status = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"current-status")]')
        if sel_current_status:
            txt_current_status = sel_current_status.xpath('./text()').extract()
            txt_current_status = " ".join(map(unicode.strip,txt_current_status))
            print txt_current_status
        else:
            print 'NO STATUS FOUND'

# YIELDS THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT FOR ME:
# [casestatus] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/mycasestatus.do;jsessionid=A19A03FC933A208A2DDF89D98BE9F32E> (referer: https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do)
# Case Rejected Because I Sent An Incorrect Fee
```

Comment: Thank you Frank. I think your solution might work but I am having the same problem as my other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132482/scrapy-shell-error. Once I fix this, then I maybe able to run successfully your solution.